# Thunderbolt 3 backwards compatibility

Tags: compatibility, thunderbolt, usb-c

Thunderbolt 3 uses a USB-C Connector. Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2 uses the Mini DisplayPort connector.

On https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq they explain that Tunderbolt 3 has backwards compatibility if you use adapters. The only adapter I could find was for $100 plus: https://www.startech.com/Cables/thunderbolt-3-cables/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-thunderbolt-adapter~TBT3TBTADAP But it seems that this device translates Thunderbolt 3 data to Thunderbolt/Thunderbolt 2 data and vice versa. So it is not a native compatibilty similar to USB 2.0 and USB 3.0. This translation results in addition of latency and power consumption.

So my guess is that Thunderbolt 3 and Thunderbolt 2 are not directly compatible and it could get difficult to connect an "old" Thunderbolt 2 device to a new Laptop Model with Thunderbolt 3/USB-C.

Is there a simple way to connect a Thunderbolt 2 Device to a Thunderbolt 3 Host without latency impact or translation? And without the need to buy additional gear for every "old" device?

It seems that this is still an unknown issue as Thunderbolt 3 computers or notebooks barely exist at the moment. But as soon as Apple is going to release a new MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt 3, telling their users that they can't use their beloved "Thunderbolt Displays" anymore, people will start to complain...

Comment: You need an adapter but there is no impact in using one

Comment: Please explain: Why no impact at all? In my understanding, Thunderbolt 2 needs to be convertet to Thunderbolt 3 somehow. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It does but there is no performance impact for that conversion.

Comment: Could you please explain why there is no impact? Sources, Articles?